# Consume json POSTed to MVC controller

Tags: c#, ajax, json, model-view-controller

I built the CSharp class Visual Studios "Paste Special" --> Json to Classes.
I would post the jsonData but it is fairly large and dont want to waste your time.
I'm guessing my `cihForm.cs` needs a constructor class but that didn't seem like the right way to go about consuming the data.

The problem seems to be that the `cihForm` class is not consuming the json data correctly. I assume it is because of the `cihForm` structure.

**View Ajax call:**

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
    url: '/Forms/Create_Post',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // get the result and do some magic with it
        var message = data.Message;
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```

**Controller Action:**

```
<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Post(jsonData As Rootobject) As JsonResult
  //jsonData seems to be blank
  // immediate window debug below
  //?jsonData
  //{CIH.Library.CSharp.cihForm}

End Function
```

**Csharp Class:**

```
namespace CIH.Library.CSharp
{

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Theform theForm { get; set; }
        }

        public class Theform
        {
            public Formoption[] formOptions { get; set; }
            public Formnotification[] formNotifications { get; set; }
            public Field[] fields { get; set; }
        }

        public class Formoption
        {
            public string reqApproval { get; set; }
            public string orderedApproval { get; set; }
            public string[] approvalStages { get; set; }
            public string reqLogin { get; set; }
            public Limitsubmission[] limitSubmissions { get; set; }
            public Formexpire[] formExpires { get; set; }
            public string attachForm { get; set; }
            public string toOrganizations { get; set; }
            public string[] orgsToAttach { get; set; }
            public string toEvents { get; set; }
            public string[] eventsToAttach { get; set; }
            public string showInAdminForms { get; set; }
            public string useAsSurvey { get; set; }
        }

        public class Limitsubmission
        {
            public string responsesPerUser { get; set; }
            public string responsesPerForm { get; set; }
        }

        public class Formexpire
        {
            public string startTime { get; set; }
            public string endTime { get; set; }
        }

        public class Formnotification
        {
            public string showSuccessMessage { get; set; }
            public string successMessage { get; set; }
            public string redirectOnSuccess { get; set; }
            public string redirectUrl { get; set; }
            public string adminNotification { get; set; }
            public string notifyAdminTo { get; set; }
            public string notifyAdminSubject { get; set; }
            public string notifyAdminbody { get; set; }
            public string submitterNotification { get; set; }
            public string submitterSubject { get; set; }
            public string submitterBody { get; set; }
        }

        public class Field
        {
            public string fieldTypeId { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string sortOrder { get; set; }
            public string isReq { get; set; }
            public string allowMultiple { get; set; }
            public string[] dropOptions { get; set; }
            public string[] listOptions { get; set; }
            public string scaleMin { get; set; }
            public string scaleMax { get; set; }
            public string allowPast { get; set; }
            public string limitToEmailDomain { get; set; }
            public string emailDomainToLimitTo { get; set; }
            public string limitFileTypes { get; set; }
            public string[] listOfLimitedFileTypes { get; set; }
            public string limitAccess { get; set; }
            public string limitToCategory { get; set; }
            public string[] limitedCategories { get; set; }
            public string limitToOrganization { get; set; }
            public string limitedOrganization { get; set; }
            public string infoTextBody { get; set; }
            public string imageCaption { get; set; }
            public string imageURL { get; set; }
        }        
}
```

Comment: `{CIH.Library.CSharp.cihForm}` (from your immediate window) would mean that `jsonData` *isn't* blank (isn't `null` at least). What exactly is missing in the `jsonData` variable?

Comment: Well i cant seem to consume the data. When i try to look deeper in my class using `?jsonData.Theform` it comes back with `Theform is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: Did you try lowercase? `theForm`?

Comment: Yes i've tried all of the cases. My View has `@ModelType CIH.Library.CSharp.Rootobject` as the model for the page. Does this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with how i was passing the class into my controller function.

This is how i went about fixing it.

1) Create JSON template using this website -- http://www.objgen.com/json

2) Create C# classes using this website -- http://json2csharp.com/

3) Create `<script>` tag on view page that does ajax call with json data

```
   <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Save</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {

            var data = //paste JSON template created in step #1 here
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Forms/Create_Post',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // get the result and do some magic with it
                var message = data.Message;
                console.log(message);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

3) I pasted the classes created in step 2 into a class file.

4) in my controller i then passed in `RootObject`

```
   <HttpPost>
    <ActionName("Create")>
    Function Create_Post(jsonData As RootObject) As ACtionResult

        Dim json As New RootObject()
        json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(jsonData.ToString())


    End Function
```